# I'm getting an error in the post like system with flutter and php?

Tags: php, flutter

I'm making an Instagram-style app and I had a hard time somewhere. When I press the like button, the like increases and when I press it again, it decreases. There is no problem here. When I press like, I want my like button to turn red, but the like buttons in the whole listview turn red! How can I make the button color change only on the post I like?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_php/login.dart';
import 'comments.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Posts extends StatefulWidget {
  const Posts({super.key});

  @override
  State<Posts> createState() => _PostsState();
}

class _PostsState extends State<Posts> {
  List<dynamic> users = [];
  var activeUser;

  String? isLiked;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPosts();
    readySharedPreferences();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 26,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        toolbarHeight: 80,
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text(
          "fishio",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.amber,
            fontSize: 32,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.2,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        color: Colors.white,
        onRefresh: () async {
          await Future.delayed(
            Duration(seconds: 1),
            fetchPosts,
          );
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: users.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              final user = users[index];
              final id = user['id'];
              final username = user['user'];
              final image = user['image'];
              final likes = user['likes'];
              return singlePost(username, image, likes, id);
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        onPressed: () {
          logout();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.login),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> readySharedPreferences() async {
    var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var currentUser = sharedPreferences.getString("currentUser");

    setState(() {
      if (currentUser != null) {
        activeUser = currentUser;
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.remove("currentUser");
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
    );
  }

  Future<void> fetchPosts() async {
    final url = "http://192.168.1.35/fishio_new/getdata.php";
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    final body = response.body;
    final json = jsonDecode(body);
    setState(() {
      users = json;
    });
  }

  Future<void> likePost(String id) async {
    final post_id = id;
    final body = {
      "user": activeUser,
      "postid": post_id,
    };

    final url = "http://192.168.1.35/fishio_new/addlike.php";
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final response = await http.post(
      uri,
      body: body,
    );

    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
  }

  Future<void> getLikes(String id) async {
    final post_id = id;
    final body = {
      "user": activeUser,
      "postid": post_id,
    };

    final url = "http://192.168.1.35/fishio_new/getlikes.php";
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final response = await http.post(
      uri,
      body: body,
    );

    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
    setState(() {
      isLiked = data[0];
    });
  }

  Widget singlePost(String username, String image, String likes, String id) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 15,
        left: 15,
        right: 15,
        bottom: 0,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(username),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: image,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 300,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.grey.shade500,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            children: [
              isLiked == "like"
                  ? GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        likePost(id).whenComplete(
                            () => fetchPosts().then((value) => getLikes(id)));
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    )
                  : GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        likePost(id).whenComplete(
                            () => fetchPosts().then((value) => getLikes(id)));
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text(likes),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Comments(id: id)),
                  );
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.comment,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I just added the relevant codes, that's not all.**

I tried many things but it doesn't work as I said. You can't do the codes. I would be very happy if you could guide me as an idea.

Comment: You have to set one bool value inside the user model

Comment: would  you share your user model class ??

Comment: I did not use a model, I created a structure this way.

Comment: can you please put inside the code of users

Comment: I updated all my codes on my page, can you take a look at my post again? By the way, sorry I'm new to flutter.

Comment: its ok, you have to make model class of your json

Comment: Please check this block
https://blog.codemagic.io/rest-api-in-flutter/

Comment: Please convert your code with model class then I will explain how you can achieve like

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "isLiked" is a global variable to this file. That's the reason why its reflecting in all the cards/tiles of the listview.

Try this approach:

- Upon clicking on like, send a put/patch request to backend for that particular post.
- Re-render the listview/that particular card by fetching the post details from backend again or from previous response.